# Using a list of IDs to combine SQL tables into a data frame in R

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, for-loop, rsqlite

I have a list of IDs that are not associated with any actual data. I have a SQL database that has a table for each of these IDs, and those tables have data that I would like to combine together into one large data frame based on the list of IDs that I have. I figured a `for` loop would be needed for this, but I haven't been able to get it to work properly.

For example I have a list of IDs"
1,2,3,4,5

I have a SQL database with tables for each of these, and they also have other data associated with the IDs. Each ID has multiple rows and columns.

I would like my end product to be the combination of those rows and columns for the list of IDs to be in a single data frame in r. How could I do this? What is the most efficient way to do so?

```
#Example data set
library(lubridate)
date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("26-12-2010"), dmy("20-12-2011"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(seq(1, 5), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

for (i in 1: length(ID)){
  ID[i] <- dbReadTable(mydb, ID[i])
}
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: You mean that you have a table in your SQL database named `1`?

Comment: Yes, I have a table for each ID in the database and I would like to read them into R  and combine them into a single data frame.

Comment: `IDs <- lapply(ID, function(i) dbReadTable(mydb, i))` should give you a list of tables. Is that what you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll expand on my comment to finish the question.

```r
IDs <- lapply(setNames(nm=ID), function(i) dbReadTable(mydb, i))
```

and then one of:

```r
## base R
IDs <- Map(function(x, nm) transform(x, id = nm), IDs, names(IDs))
DF <- do.call(rbind, IDs)

## dplyr
DF <- dplyr::bind_rows(IDs, .id = "id")

## data.table
DF <- data.table::rbindlist(IDs, idcol = "id")
```

The addition of the `"id"` column is to easily differentiate the rows based on the source `ID`. If the table already includes that, then you can omit the `Map` (base) and `.id`/`idcol` arguments.

(This assumes, btw, that all tables have the same exact structure: same column names and same data types.)